# Detect resource usage in BlackBerry Webworks

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I've looked through the API documentation and haven't found an answer.

We're doing some activities (encrypting and manipulating potentially large files) and are hitting memory issues.

I need some way of determining memory usage so that I can estimate the maximum limits of the files we're working with.

Has anyone seen done this, or have any idea how to go about it?